# add sections/cluster from users end in html via choices or any other approach

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-3.0

Suppose im saving a url from a texbox given by user the URL is submitted by user and its saved to my models and now what i wanna do is let the user add different sections/clusters such as technology,sports etc from his end suppose where he inputs the URL there itself he can define that cluster/section and save that particular URL to the particular section/cluster he made or selected in the option is the section/cluster was already there! could anyone help or give me a small example for the same? what would be a better approach do it with django choices or some other way?

TIA.

```
ill paste the current code below :

form.py

class UrlSaveForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UrlSaveModel
        fields = ['the_url']


models.py (below)

class UrlSaveModel(models.Model):

    the_url = EmbedVideoField()

    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.desc


HTML for saving: save.html


{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'func' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
      >Enter the URL here to save video to the library:</label
    >
    <textarea
      class="form-control"
      id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
      rows="2"
      name="the_url"
      placeholder="Enter the URL here"
    ></textarea>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Save URL</button>
  </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}


"""and little snippet of views.py"""

if form.is_valid():

                print('form is valid')

                posted_url = request.POST['the_url']
                yt = YouTube(posted_url)

                description = yt.title
                print('description-extracted:', description)

                print('Posted_url', posted_url)
                obj = UrlSaveModel(desc=description, the_url=posted_url)
                obj.save()

                return HttpResponse('saved sucessfully!')
```